# How do I determine empty space inside a div and add content to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container that is 100px wide and I have 5 sets of different sized divs to dynamically fill that container by clicking their corresponding buttons. I am trying to figure out how I would go about finding the empty space within the container to place a properly fitting element. For example, if there is an 80x80 placed first and then a 100x80 underneath. The first element has not reached max width and has an open space of 20x80. Using jQuery how would I determine that the empty space next to the 80x80 is where the next element of 20x80 should be placed?

I have tried to find a solution on google but have failed to return any results similar to what I'm trying to do.

```js
$("#Test").on('click', function() {
  $('.fill-container').append("<div class='box1'></div>")
});
$("#Test2").on('click', function() {
  $('.fill-container').append("<div class='box2'></div>")
});
$("#Test3").on('click', function() {
  $('.fill-container').append("<div class='box3'></div>")
});
$("#Test4").on('click', function() {
  $('.fill-container').append("<div class='box4'></div>")
});
$("#Test5").on('click', function() {
  $('.fill-container').append("<div class='box5'></div>")
});
```

```css
.fill-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 600px;
  outline: black solid 1px;
}

.controls {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.box1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

.box2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}

.box3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.box4 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.box5 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fill-container"></div>
<div class="controls">
  <button id="Test">50x70</button>
  <button id="Test2">50x70</button>
  <button id="Test3">80x80</button>
  <button id="Test4">20x80</button>
  <button id="Test5">100x80</button>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Comment: It would be vastly easier to use something like CSS Grid and perhaps coordinate it with JQuery/JS - is that acceptable? The problem is, even if you figure out what the distance is, rendering is from top-down, so you would end up having to rewrite the guts of the parent every time so that they're rendered in a specific order. The issue doesn't lend itself to a simple append.

Comment: @StevenStark the `window.innerHeight` property isn't going to help when you're looking at an HTMLDivElement that's 100px wide.

Comment: @zfrisch And why not? innerHeight | innerWidth is what's used here.

Comment: ? In the example you posted? innerHeight and innerWidth is available on Window, it's not a property of HTMLElement. Can you explain how you think it helps?

Comment: @zfrisch Your answer for coordinating CSS Grid and jQuery is the appropriate route, thank you!